# Express routes stopped working after setting app in production on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I've deployed my app on Heroku and after some tweaking, everything works except when I try to retrieve data from the Mongo database. The console error I get is: *Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.*

I have the feeling that it won't go into the get request while that should be the case. (Because it's not logging anything in the console)

Am I missing something in the way routes are handled in production?
Everything in development is working.

I'm very confused at this point, hope someone can help me

Server.js:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const cors = require('cors')
const compression = require('compression');
const helmet = require('helmet')

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(helmet())
app.use(compression());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'client/build'); 
const apiPath = path.join(__dirname, 'api'); 

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use('/overview', express.static(apiPath));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));    
   })

}


app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(bodyParser.json())


const apiRouter = require('./api/api');

app.use('/overview', apiRouter);
// connect to the db and start the express server
let db;


const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI

MongoClient.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true,}, (err, client) => {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('mongo connected')
    db = client.db('kvdlaanmeldingen');
    // start the express web server listening on port 5000
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
  });
```

apiRouter, api.js in api/api.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const apiRouter = express.Router()
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI
console.log('api.js is activated') //this is logged to console, so file can be read.

let db;

MongoClient.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true,}, (err, client) => {
    db = client.db('kvdlaanmeldingen');
  });


  let aanmeldingen = [];
// this is where I believe it gets stuck
apiRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(db)
    db.collection('kvdlaanmeldingen').countDocuments({}, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result)
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
    })
  });



module.exports = apiRouter;
```

The get request should be done as soon as this React component is rendered:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Aanmeldingen.css';
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import XPress from './utils/Xpress.js';
import TaakComponent from './TaakComponent';
import { snakeCase } from "snake-case";



class Aanmeldingen extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dataLoaded: 0,
        taken: [// an array of different names that will be loaded as headers],
        taakKlik: false,
        taakData: null,
        taakNaam: null,
      }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
      XPress.getTaken().then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data) {
          this.setState({
            taakData: data,
            dataLoaded: 1,
            });
        }
      });      
     }

{...}


render(){
  return (

        <div className="Aanmeldingenpage">
            <div className="statistics" onClick={this.aanmeldingen}>
            <p className="statistics" id="counterAanmeldingen">{this.state.dataLoaded ? `Aantal aanmeldingen: ${this.state.taakData}` : 'Data aan het laden..'}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
  );
}
}
```

and Xpress.getTaken is looking like this:

```js
const XPress = {};
const baseUrl = window.location.origin;


XPress.getTaken = () => {
    const url = `${baseUrl}/overview`;
    return fetch(url, {method: 'GET'}).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve([]));
          }      
       return response.json().then(jsonResponse => {
        return jsonResponse
       } 
       )   
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you posted is often seen when parsing JSON fails. I guess this happens when fetch fails to parse the result in the frontend at this line: `return response.json().then(jsonResponse => {`.

Instead of returning valid JSON, the backend returns a file that starts with "<" (the unexpected token). Your backend responds with an HTML page instead of JSON.

Issue comes from here most likely:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));    
})
```

This basically says that all GET requests should serve `index.html`. That's why the request doesn't go to `apiRouter.get('/')`, it stops at the first match, which is the code above. It works on localhost because this code path is inside a conditional that checks NODE_ENV for production.

Not sure why you have it in there, but removing it would solve the issue.

Comment: result doesn't get logged to the console because apparently it doesn't reach that part.
However, I now tried to do a post request, which seems to be working smoothly and adds user input to the right document `kvdlaanmeldingen`
.That is done in the same file with `apiRouter.post('/kvdlaanmeldingen', (req, res) => { ... }`

Comment: I have added the front end code to my original post, maybe that helps

Comment: The frontend files had the clue. I've edited my answer.

Comment: YES this was what was causing this issue! 
I originally had it in place for server the index file but apparently with the rest of the code that was not needed. Deleted it and works now! Thanks so much

Comment: Yeey  awesome. With a little digging, every bug is squashable eventually. Don't forget to check as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the heroku postbuild script to your json file in the root directory as same as the existence of the server.js file, that might help, using in react we must add heroku postbiuld so that the build is saved in the server, and that might not produce an issue,

Comment: thanks, but I did add heroku postbuild   
`"main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  } `

Comment: I think it needs a flag before all the texts in the postbuild script "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false"

Comment: Can you show me exactly what to define there? I ran `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` but this makes no difference. The postbuild script is left the same

Comment: This is what i regularly do when i post apps to heroku,                                    
                                                                                                                            
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix (React Frontend Folder Name) react-fastrack && npm run build --prefix (React Frontend Folder Name)react-fastrack"
  },